# How to set GCM priority with Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am currently using `Azure Push Notification Service` to send messages to android phones. According to [This link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) you can set the priority of a GCM message to help deal with apps in Doze mode.

Here is how I currently use it:

```
     string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new GCMCarrier(data));
     result = await Gethub().SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(content, toTag);
```

here is GCMCarrier

```
 public class GCMCarrier
 {
    public GCMCarrier(Object _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }
 }
```

Now how do I add priority to the message? The constructor to send a GCM only has a data parameter?

Or can I simply add it to my `GCMCarrier" object along with data?

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to the way someone use - add the Priority field to the payload. It was discussed recently in the Github repository [as the issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/issues/19). Windows Phone has that functionality in the SDK, while it looks like the Android does not. But Notification Hubs, AFAIK, is pass-through mechanism, so the payload will be treated by GCM itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance your current  model and add required properties in correct format and then convert it to json payload.

```
public class GcmNotification
{
    [JsonProperty("time_to_live")]
    public int TimeToLiveInSeconds { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; } 
    public NotificationMessage Data { get; set; }
}


 public class NotificationMessage
 {
   public NotificationDto Message { get; set; }
 }

 public class NotificationDto
 {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
 }
```

***Now you can convert your data with json converter but remember use lowercase setting in JsonConverter otherwise there might be expection on device. I have implementation of this in LowercaseJsonSerializer class.***

```
 private void SendNotification(GcmNotification gcmNotification,string tag)
  {
                var payload = LowercaseJsonSerializer.SerializeObject(gcmNotification);
                var notificationOutcome = _hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(payload, tag).Result;
 }

public class LowercaseJsonSerializer
    {
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver()
        };

        public static string SerializeObject(object o)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o,Settings);
        }

        public class LowercaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
        {
            protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
            {
                return propertyName.ToLower();
            }
        }
    }
```